# Activity in stack

Tags: android, android-activity

```
oIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                               | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);

                    //oIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
                    oIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
                    startActivity(oIntent);
                    finish();
```

I have use the following set of code to clear activiites...it works fine...in some scenario...the blank activity is started...i think it is because of starting new task in flag...i dont want that empty activity/...how to solve this?

Comment: I struggle lot from this

Comment: What do you mean by "the blank activity"? Using `CLEAR_TASK` will cause all activities in the task to be finished and a new instance of the target Activity will be created. If you are using `CLEAR_TASK` you don't need to also specify `CLEAR_TOP`.

Comment: this is the code used for exit...in another activity ... when the code reaches finish   in this oIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);     startActivity(oIntent);  finish()  ...the blank activity is created....and then finish occur..small transisition makes emty page..how to solve this

Comment: if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) 
  {
   System.out.println("&&&&&&login");
   finish();
    System.exit(0);
  }

Comment: Is the root Activity (the one you are starting in `oIntent`) always in the activity stack? I mean, does the root Activity call `finish()` when it launches other activities?

Comment: Also, calling `System.exit()` is a bad idea. You don't want to do this.

Comment: any code to get this perfectly...clearing all the activities?

Comment: PLoginDialog.this.finish();
   moveTaskToBack(true); 
   //android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()); 
   System.exit(1); is this correct?

Comment: If you have called `finish()` on the only Activity in the task, then you don't need to move the task to the background. If there are no live activities, the task will get cleaned up by Android, and the hosting OS process as well.

Answer (score 0):

Api 21++

```
ActivityManager am =(ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<AppTask> ap = am.getAppTasks(); 
ap.get(0).finishAndRemoveTask();
```

Api 21--

from what Sir **@David Wasser** pointed, just use that and mantain your putExtra code and in your onCreate of your Target `Activity` check if it has an Extra key of *Exit* and call `finish()` immediately

Comment: if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) 
  {
   System.out.println("&&&&&&login");
   finish();
    System.exit(0);
  }

Comment: this is the code used for exit...in another activity ... when the code reaches finish   in this oIntent.putExtra("EXIT", true);     startActivity(oIntent);  finish()  ...the blank activity is created....and then finish occur..small transisition makes emty page..how to solve this